# Why does this print undefined? When I use a variable other than ${name} it works

Tags: javascript, variables, local-storage, undefined

I am having a problem accessing a global variable in a key event. When I use `name` it prints undefined, but if i use `anotherVariableName` it works. Does anyone know why? The following code is done in javascript.

```
var name = {
    "key": "value"
}

document.onkeyup = function (event) {
    console.log("name is", name["key"])
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtbHZ.png

Comment: please share in which language you are trying this and also share code which you have tried so far

Comment: This is done in javascript. Thought I attached an image. It's there now

Comment: @abm, when you declare the variable `name` with `var` it clashes with the browsers `window.name` property. Use `let` or `const`!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. It's working.

```
const name = {
    "key": "value"
}

document.onkeyup = function (event) {
    console.log("name is", name.key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are shadowing the name property on the window object.  You can use ES6 syntax (let or const) or you can use another variable name.

Answer (score 0):

The global window object has already a `name` property which is the name of the current window. Hence when you use `name` it returns the name of the window which is of type `string`. so when you do `name["key"]` it is checking for property `key` in a string which is `undefined` all the time.

You can either use a different variable name or you can use ES6 `let` or `const` to declare your variable.

Answer (score 0):

As [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) says,

> The scope of a variable declared with `var` is its current execution context,
>   which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global.
>   If you re-declare a JavaScript variable, it will not lose its value.

In this case, `name` is global and it points already existing variable, `window.name`.

Also, according to [Window.name page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name),

> `window.name` will convert all values to their string representations by using the `toString` method.

So value of `name` is `"[object Object]"` that is `String`. You can check this by

```
var name = {"key":"value"};
console.log(name); // [object Object]
```

`key` property of `String` value `"[object Object]"` is undefined, this is why you get `undefined`.